# Safest way of counting URL clicks

Tags: url, click

I have a startup idea, which has something to do with counting URL clicks from users. And I am researching ways to make it hacker safe, just as Google ads identify suspicious clicks. What criteria should I take into account when handling this problem? IP address, click pattern, MAC address, anything else?

Also, is it possible to handle fake clicks coming from users who constantly change their IP address through VPN maybe?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://support.flippa.com/hc/en-us/articles/202891420-What-is-fake-traffic-How-can-I-identify-it-) describes fake traffic and gives information on how to determine wether traffic is real or fake. The process to determine fake traffic requires a lot of data analysis and is not an easy matter, as the software for creating fake traffic improve.

As stated in the article, you should consider these data:

- Bounce Rate: An extremely high Bounce Rate may be cause for concern.
- Pages/Session: An extremely low Pages/Session may be cause for concern.
- Avg. Session Duration: An extremely short Avg. Session Duration may be cause for concern.
- New Sessions: An extremely high percentage of New Sessions may be cause for concern. Likewise, an extremely low percentage of New Sessions may also be cause for concern.

IP blocking might not be useful, but you can identify the same user on different IP addresses by looking at their unique [browser fingerprint](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/12/01/browser-fingerprints-the-invisible-cookies-you-cant-delete/).